# Angular view doesn't load data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created an Angular view to display some data fetched from an api. The data gets stored in an array. However, the page is blank. The html page doesn't show anything.

ts:

```
/*
*  Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
*  See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information.
*/

import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';
import {AssignmentService} from '../services/AssignmentService';
import {Assignment} from '../models/Assignment';
import {MeService} from '../services/me.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [AssignmentService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  me: MicrosoftGraph.User;
  assignments: Assignment[];
  ready: boolean;

  constructor(private meService: MeService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private service: AssignmentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.meService.getMe().subscribe(me => {
        this.me = me;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {
        this.setAssignments();
      });
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }



onLogin() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  private setAssignments() {
    this.service.getOpenAssignments(this.me.mail).subscribe(assignments => {
        this.assignments = assignments;
        this.ready = true;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.assignments);
      });
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div *ngIf="ready">
  <div *ngFor="let assignment of assignments" class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <h2 class="display-4 d-inline"> {{assignment.name}} </h2>
        <p class="lead d-inline"> {{assignment.created | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </p>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary"> {{assignment.domain}} </span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" [routerLink]="['/assignment/', assignment.name]">
          Meer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <hr class="my-4"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <div *ngIf="assignment.description.length < 100">
          <p class="lead">
            {{ assignment.description }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="assignment.description.length > 100">
          <p class="lead">
            {{ assignment.description.substr(0,100) + '...' }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data gets loaded. Assignments and me are filled and stored with the correct data...

Anybody got an idea?

Thanks in advance!

edit: The JSON response is "OK". It returns the data. Ready is not getting set anywhere else, also no errors in console. If I remove the ngIf directive, it's just a blank page. Same as it is with ngIf directive. I think this means that assignments is empty or undefined when the page is rendered?

edit_2: this is my service

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AssignmentService implements OnInit {

  BASE_API_URL = 'http://10.50.70.21:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getOpenAssignments(user: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_API_URL + '/assignments/open/' + user).catch(this.onError);
  }

  getAssignment(name: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_API_URL + '/assignments/' + name).catch(this.onError);
  }

  onError(res: Response): Observable<any> {
    const error = 'Error ${res.status}: ${res.statusText}';
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

}
```

Comment: please post what JSON response you are getting in service reply

Comment: hope you are not setting ready to false somewhere else; btw any errors in console ?

Comment: Breakdown the issue by removing the `*ngIf="ready"` and checking that the data displays correctly. If it does, you can start investigating why the `ready` flag is not set correctly, if it doesn't you know that your JSON reply is faulty somehow,

Comment: The JSON response is "OK". It returns the data. Ready is not getting set anywhere else, also no errors in console.

If I remove the ngIf directive, it's just a blank page. Same as it is with ngIf directive. I think this means that assignments is empty or undefined when the page is rendered?

Comment: does code reaches `console.log(this.assignments);` in `setAssignments()`?

Comment: Can you still post the JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using observables. The template is already rendered when the data has not yet been fetched to your app, thus it shows a blank page.
Store your observables in variables and display them in your template with the async pipe, like this:

**.ts**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [AssignmentService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  me: Observable<any>;
  assignments: Observable<Assignment[]>;
  meSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private meService: MeService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private service: AssignmentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.me = this.meService.getMe();
    this.assignements = this.setAssignements(this.me);
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

onLogin() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  private setAssignments(user$) {
   return user$.mergeMap(user => {
       return this.service.getOpenAssignments(user.mail);
   });
  }
}
```

**template**

Here I just put an async (first line) to wait for the data

```
<div *ngIf="(assignements | async) as assignementsArray">
  <div *ngFor="let assignment of assignementsArray" class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <h2 class="display-4 d-inline"> {{assignment.name}} </h2>
        <p class="lead d-inline"> {{assignment.created | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </p>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary"> {{assignment.domain}} </span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" [routerLink]="['/assignment/', assignment.name]">
          Meer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <hr class="my-4"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <div *ngIf="assignment.description.length < 100">
          <p class="lead">
            {{ assignment.description }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="assignment.description.length > 100">
          <p class="lead">
            {{ assignment.description.substr(0,100) + '...' }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However "pipe" was not found, nor was "tap", the two functions you added. I've added my service to the question for more clarity.

Comment: then it means your using an older rxjs version (probably 4.x). I'll make an update.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use .json()

```
 private setAssignments() {
    this.service.getOpenAssignments(this.me.mail).subscribe(assignments => {
        this.assignments = assignments.json();
        this.ready = true;
      },
```